# On the definition of singular points for algebraic curves

Tags: geometry, curves, algebraic-curves, singularity

For simplicity, let us consider curves in the Euclidean plane ${\mathbb{R}}^2$. They may be defined as the set of points $(x_1, x_2)$ satisfying an equation of the form $P(x_1,x_2)=0$ where $P(x_1, x_2)$ is the polynomial

${\displaystyle P(x_1, x_2)=a_{0}+b_{0}x_1+b_{1}x_2+c_{0}x_1^{2}+2c_{1}x_1x_2+c_{2}x_2^{2}+\dots }$

> **Definition**.  The singular points are those on the curve whose partial derivatives vanish
> $${\displaystyle \nabla P(x_1,x_2)=0 \quad \operatorname{or}\quad {\frac {\partial P}{\partial x_1}}={\frac {\partial P}{\partial x_2}}=0.}$$

I think I don't see the point (no pun intended). Usually, the term 'singularity' in maths means 'lacking of differentiability' or '(locally) bad behaviour'. The null gradient sounds more like a stationary point here. I mean.. what could go wrong if the curve has a null gradient? What's 'singular' about it?

Comment: Hint: plot the curves $y^2=x^2$, $y^2=x^3$. What are the singular points, according to the definition? Can you see any kind of distinguishing feature on the curve? Compare with eg $y^2=x^2+x$.

Comment: The condition means the curve has a $2$-dimensional tangent space at that point. The easiest example to really see what goes wrong here is $P(x, y) = xy$, which is two lines crossing at the origin.